# Power BI row reduction while summarizing a column

Tags: powerbi, aggregate

I'm sure the nature of my question will reveal I am a rookie at PowerBI.  -- so, please, don't hesitate to write like you're writing to a 10 year old.  I have a table with several records per person (sorted by person).  Each record has a Weight.  I want my PowerBi report to display only one record per person with the sum of all that person's weights.  There might be a wrinkle in that the weight is in a different table (two tables away via two relationships).  Since I am in learn mode, don't mind if solution comes in progressively more difficult steps (as the weight table gets further away from the people table).

Data model:

```
- 'PersonTable' related to 'TestTable' by 'Name'
- 'TestTable' related to 'WeightTable' by 'Test'
```

I have tried creating a new column (not measure) in the PersonTable (and I have tried putting a new column in the TestTable) and then using various formulas to try to sum the weights in the WeightsTable - to no avail.  The summed weights always come back including the sum of all possible weights in the WeightsTable.

Here is some contrived test data and expected results....

```
* Name        Test     Weight
* ------     -----    ------
* Dave        TestA      3
* Dave        TestC      5
* Dave        TestE      7
* Harold      TestA      3
* Harold      TestB      4
* Jack        TestD      6
* Jack        TestE      7
```

Desired Results:

```
* Dave                   15
* Harold                  7
* Jack                   13
```

I have concocted a "codeless solution"  using the groupby feature.  I am dissatisfied with it though because I believe this approach will not allow me to "drilldown" through one of the aggregated records produced to see the detailed records that were grouped.  That will be the subject of my next question.

Here is the "solution"...

1. Use the "Query  Editor" to modify the 'TestTable'.
2. Merge the query for the 'WeightTable' into the query for the 'TestTable' keeping only the weight column from the merged in table.
3. Duplicate the new column.  (I thought I would want two columns so that I could keep the un-grouped weights for detail reporting, but this has not been the case yet.
4. Push the "GroupBy" button on the ribbon for the "Home" tab and fill out form as follows...

   - Radio Button - Basic
   - Group by: "Name"
   - New Column Name: "Sum of Weights"
   - Operation: "Sum"
   - Column: "Weight-Copy"

This generated the values I am looking for but removed the columns holding the detail data in the 'TestTable' which I will need for later (possibly drillthrough) reporting.  So I continue to seek a better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've chosen a proper solution, up until step 4. Remove that step and load the joined dataset into the data model.

Then, just drag and drop the desired columns onto the canvas (weight and name). PowerBI will automatically sum the weights and then group that by name, producing your desired output.